# Android Studio 1.1 Gradle 2.2.1 Gradle version 2.1 required current version is 2.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am just trying to compile the latest version of u2020-daggr2 in Android stu![e  I imported it as a gradle project.  But I get error complaining about gradle! I did edit the gradle-wrapper.properties. Rebuilding however did not work.  I did see: [Gradle 2.1 is required Migrate to Gradle wrapper and sync project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311467/gradle-2-1-is-required-migrate-to-gradle-wrapper-and-sync-project)  which seems like same issue but on Studio I did not find:

Settings -> Gradle and click Use default gradle wrapper (recommended).

I did not find where to do this in Studio. First off there is no menu that just says Setting.  There is :  File->Other Setting->Default Setting.  But nothing but gradle vm parameters etc. Nothing about using default gradle wrapper. 
[image]  Do I need to have a local copy of gradle 2.1 for this to work? [image] ![enter image description here][4] 
[image]

gradle wrapper.properties is edited as such:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip

Error:(20) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'u2020-dagger2'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
>   Gradle version 2.1 is required. Current version is 2.2.1. If using the       gradlewrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/Mac1/Downloads/u2020-dagger2  /gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.1-all.zip

Comment: do you have the latest gradle downloaded?

Comment: You go to file settings under that you will findle plugins gradle. You can use the local gradle copy instead of the one from your project.  Use the latest gradel version

Comment: Let me check this. Actually no.  File -> Setting does not exist

Comment: I've added screenshots so people don't just throw these statements around like it's under project->settings or file->settings.  No its not.

Comment: it is i can also post a screen shot. or you can update your gradel by goto plugins gradle. I am not sure what version of android-studio you are using

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73465/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-mobile-man).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204272/how-to-tell-when-gradle-wrapper-is-on-off-in-android-studio  Any ideas?

Comment: Check the following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460349/gradle-version-1-8-is-required-current-version-is-1-6?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use this gradle-plugin in your `build.gradle`

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
```

Android Studio 1.1.0 requires:

- Gradle 2.2.1  (you can set this value in the `gradle-wrapper.properties`)
- Gradle plugin 1.0.0/1.1.0 (you can set this value in your `build.gradle`)

Comment: Are you talking about in here: dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.3'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.1.0'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.0'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
  }

Comment: And is there a place in studio to tell studio to use the wrapper.

Comment: You have to change the 0.13.3 in 1.1.0. You can edit the files. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27993506/2016562

Comment: This works. Still wondering if there is on/off switch for wrapper somewhere.

Comment: Hey Gabriele, I'm still wondering about the wrapper? Studio/Gradle don't seem to know if its on/off and neither do I.  What determines if wrapper is used or not? Do you know when the wrapper is on or off?

Comment: Where can I find the most updated version of gradle to put there? It seems that as opposed to repos, Android-Studio doesn't tell me about new versions for this. Currently what I've found is 1.3.1, while Android-Studio puts 1.3.0 as the default one.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Use the plugin 1.3.1 and gradle 2.5.

For a full list:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659079/cant-update-to-android-studio-gradle-1-4-plugin/32659415#32659415
For a full compatibility list:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252956/android-studio-gradle-issue-upgrading-to-version-0-5-0-gradle-migrating-from-0/22256954#22256954

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti So you mean I need to check this website for the newest version: https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/revisions/gradle-plugin.html ?

Comment: Not only, there are some beta versions: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I don't understand how to find on the link you've provided, which version of gradle to put...

Answer (score 6):

click on your build.gradle file in project explorer and make changes as

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2
}
```

ReBuild your project! Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems to fix the build issue yes

Comment: chect this may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460349/gradle-version-1-8-is-required-current-version-is-1-6?rq=1