# Can't update to Android Studio gradle 1.4 plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In my `build.gradle` I have:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.+'
    }
}
```

However I'm getting:

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.+.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/AndroidStudio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.4.1/gradle-1.4.1.pom
    file:/C:/AndroidStudio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.4.1/gradle-1.4.1.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.4.1/gradle-1.4.1.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.4.1/gradle-1.4.1.jar
Required by:
    :xxx:unspecified
```

What to do?

Comment: Where did you find the 1.4.1? It doesn't exist here: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.android.tools.build%22%20AND%20a%3A%22gradle%22

Comment: Doesn't work with 1.4.0 either

Comment: Because it doesn't exist

Comment: where did you get that number from?

Comment: Try to replace version with '1.4.0'. Using '+' often doesn't work for versions ending with 0.

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti It should exist there. It exists at jcenter.

Comment: Use classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta2 with jcenter

Comment: 1.5.0 is available now (seems like no stable 1.4 release was ever published).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It happens because the gradle plugin for android **1.4.+** **doesn't exist** (currently) in **central maven**.

You can check [here the full list](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.android.tools.build%22%20AND%20a%3A%22gradle%22) of the versions available on Central Maven.

Use the last stable version:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
```

If you want to use the **beta version** you have to use **jcenter** and

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()    
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta6'
    }
}
```

Here the [jcenter full list](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view).

**EDIT 03/11/2015**
Also the **beta plugin 1.5.x** is only on jcenter.

```
buildscript {
     repositories {
         jcenter()
     }
     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0-beta1'
     }
}
```

Comment: No, I need 1.4 for svg support. And it does exist at jcenter

Comment: Where do you find this info about updated/beta versions of gradle? This is so confusing on official Google documentation (do they ever update imports there?).

Comment: Version 1.5.0 of the gradle plugin is now in the Central Repository, so all you need to do now is update your gradle dependency to "1.5.0" in your top level `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 2):

Huh, I've replaced mavenCentral() with jcenter() and now it finds the plugin.

I wonder if this is a bug in the build system.

Comment: I don't thunk a bug, jcenter is a super set of mavenCentral

Answer (score 0):

**classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'**

works for me

But better to get the last version [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.android.tools.build%22%20AND%20a%3A%22gradle%22)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Android Studio version (if you are on alpha or beta build) matches the gradle plugin version.  For example, on my machine I had to make sure that my **Android Studio 2.0 beta 2** matches the plugin via
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2'`

Answer (score -2):

Add multiDexEnabled true

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xyz.jgeovani.loginactivity"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true // This instruction is possibitou use classpath '...tools.build:gradle:1.4.+'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

For using gradle 1.4.+

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```